# iOS Swift Google Maps - mapView didTapMarker not working?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I'm learning and getting my head around swift/google maps API. However, no matter what I try, when I tap on the marker I cannot get the print statement to appear in the console.

Tapping the marker displays the marker Name, however it never prints. I've tried a few variations of the private func found online, but maybe I'm missing something more fundamental here...

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        struct MarkerStruct {
            let name: String
            let lat: CLLocationDegrees
            let long: CLLocationDegrees
        }

        let markers = [
            MarkerStruct(name: "Food Hut 1", lat: 52.649030, long: 1.174155),
            MarkerStruct(name: "Foot Hut 2", lat: 52.649030, long: 1.174185),
        ]

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 52.649030, longitude: 1.174155, zoom: 14)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        mapView.delegate = self
        self.view = mapView

        for marker in markers {
            let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: marker.lat, longitude: marker.long)
            let locationmarker = GMSMarker(position: position)
            locationmarker.title = marker.name
            locationmarker.map = mapView
        }
    }

    private func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker) {
        print("Marker tapped")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using an old method name and you also need remove the `private` keyword, that is why your delegate method is not called

**now is**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
     print("Marker tapped")
     return true 
}
```

working now

Comment: Reinier,

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p.html#ae291e1bff99f9d06428ced09daf5802d

Thank you - Much appreciated. Could you confirm my understanding then?

If (void) is displayed at the begging, the function doesn't specify its return data. (BOOL) means the function will return a bool so I must declare that?

I'm a little unsure of the _ use but I'll do some research there :)

Comment: Also....

After adding the bool, xcode told me the new function name, however that function name isn't listed on the above page! It's still didTapMarker :(

Comment: You can go always to the `GMSMapViewDelegate` protocol declaration and see how its declared there @ScottRobinson but the autocomplete of swift must help you anyway, in objective C the declaration is `- (BOOL)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker`which is very confusing